# Java: Spock force to fail test on unrecorded mock invocation

Tags: java, spock

I have java code and test written using groovy spock. Normally test follows this pattern

My sample Java Code

```
public User findUser(String id){
   return userRepo.findById(id);
}
```

my sample test

```
def "My Test"(){
  given:
  String id = "sample"

  and:
  1 * userRepoMock.findById(id) >> testUser

  when:
  User user = userServiceUnderTest.findUser(id);

  then:
  user == testUser
}
```

where `and` contains mock with invocation count.

Now imagine someone added another invocation to method in future. like

```
public User findUser(String id){
   anotherRepo.removeTypeById(id);
   return userRepo.findById(id);
}
```

even with this code change above test will pass without any modification. How can i tell spock to fail on unrecorded mock invocation. in this case `anotherRepo.removeTypeById(id);` . I want if someone add another invocation he/she forced to update the test correctly

Comment: How are `userRepo` and `anotherRepo` defined in your spec? Are they really both mocks? Is it really easier to paste incomplete snippets than an actual [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would make your problem reproducible? Please learn how to ask better questions. Your reward would be quicker and more helpful answers.

Comment: @Viraj Interactions belong in the `then`-block as documented in https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_mocking and  https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you are overspecifying your test. This kind of test is bound to be brittle. You should not use interaction testing unless it is absolutely vital for verifying the correct application behaviour.

Having said that, with what little information you provide in your question and some educated guesses, I think you might want something like

```java
0 * anotherRepoMock._(*_)
```

Here is a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which would have been your job to provide. Please do that next time, otherwise I am not going to answer again and others might not feel it is worth their time either.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70029352

class User {
  String id
  String name

  boolean equals(o) {
    if (this.is(o)) return true
    if (getClass() != o.class) return false

    User user = (User) o

    if (id != user.id) return false
    if (name != user.name) return false

    return true
  }

  int hashCode() {
    int result
    result = id.hashCode()
    result = 31 * result + name.hashCode()
    return result
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70029352

class Another {
  String id
  int amount
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70029352

class UserRepository {
  List<User> users = [
    new User(id: "a", name: "Alice"),
    new User(id: "b", name: "Bob"),
    new User(id: "c", name: "Claire")
  ]

  User findById(String id) {
    users.findAll { it.id == id }?.first()
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70029352

class AnotherRepository {
  List<Another> anothers = [
    new Another(id: "1", amount: 111),
    new Another(id: "2", amount: 222),
    new Another(id: "3", amount: 333)
  ]

  void removeTypeById(String id) {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70029352

class UserService {
  UserRepository userRepo
  AnotherRepository anotherRepo

  User findUser(String id){
    anotherRepo.removeTypeById(id)
    userRepo.findById(id)
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70029352

import spock.lang.Specification

class UserServiceTest extends Specification {
  UserRepository userRepoMock = Mock()
  AnotherRepository anotherRepoMock = Mock()
  UserService userServiceUnderTest = new UserService(userRepo: userRepoMock, anotherRepo: anotherRepoMock)
  User testUser = new User(id: "x", name: "Xander")

  def "My Test"() {
    given:
    String id = "sample"

    // Like Leonard said, it would be better to move these interactions
    // to the 'then:' block. I am just trying to make your code run
    // with minimal changes.
    and:
    1 * userRepoMock.findById(id) >> testUser
    0 * anotherRepoMock._(*_)

    when:
    User user = userServiceUnderTest.findUser(id);

    then:
    user == testUser
  }
}
```

Running this specification will yield the following error:

```
Too many invocations for:

0 * anotherRepoMock._(*_)   (1 invocation)

Matching invocations (ordered by last occurrence):

1 * anotherRepoMock.removeTypeById('sample')   <-- this triggered the error
```

Comment: I think the op wants ` 0 * _` see https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_strict_mocking, also see my comment above about interactions belonging in the `then` block.

Comment: Maybe. That depends on how specific or generic the catch-all interaction is meant to be. Hard to tell from the fragmentary information given in the question.

Comment: FYI, I added a comment concerning moving the interactions to the `then:` block to the example specification.